# Linux script with cd and read

Tags: linux, cd

Is there any way I can integrate `cd` command with read?

```
read -p "location" loc

cd /home/dir/$loc
```

Comment: How exactly is it that your _original_ code isn't working? Is it just that you want it to be something you can put into an alias? If so, you can use a function: `read_and_cd() { read -p "location" loc && cd "/home/dir/$loc"; }` defines a `read_and_cd` command. Either way, though -- to be on-topic, a question should specify a _specific problem_; it's not clear what problem your original code has.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can; it's not pretty, but it works. :)

```
cd /home/dir/$( read -p "location" loc; echo $loc)
```

It's also a bit **costly** as it invokes a sub-shell.

Comment: Is there a way whereit does not invoke a subshell

Comment: @John  There may be, I'm just not aware of one.

Comment: @John - what's the objective, anyway? Just a way to get to a certain directory from anywhere in the file-system quickly?

Comment: I would like to make a script that can be used to navigate through directories based on the values that the user inputted.

Comment: Ex. The user typed "john" and "5" then he will go to /home/dir/john_5 in the same shell

Comment: Have you considered just using `wcd` rather than reinventing the wheel?